Make a bootable Mac USB (NOT AN INSTALLER) on a Late 2020 M1 Mac
I am wondering if you can make an USB bootable without using a Bootable MacOS Monterey, Ventura, etc. I am asking you guys, if I have to add some special EFI partition with files in the USB or if I have to use some jailbreak to make an USB force bootable (if it exists), because since I am on a M1 Mac, USBs can't be bootable by adding a EFI folder in the base partition of the USB like the Intel Ones.

How do you make an USB bootable on an Intel Mac by "a simple format erase"?

Is this a theoretical question or have you picked out a specific version of a specific OS to run on one of the M1 Mac from 2020? There is no jailbreak needed to run untrusted OS either on internal storage or external storage but you do need that OS to exchange keys with the SEP.
